# How to start Flask+Celery application?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am building a web server using Flask and Celery. I originally started them using two terminals. This was annoying because it slowed down debugging (start start, stop stop, etc) and meant that I had two logging streams. I then switched to using the `multiprocessing` module to start Celery from within Flask. This is nonoptimal because `multiprocessing` cannot be used with Flask's reloading feature, but it's nice because all my logs are coming from one application and can be managed easily.

I'm considering using Supervisor to allow me to start and stop the services as a group and have all the logs delivered to one console. Is this a reasonable choice, or are there other options that I'm missing? I know this is a bit subjective, but I cannot seem to find much information on this after a lot of searching so any reasonable answer is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just in case, did you consider this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/ ? Because there it seems there is a recipe to start celery from Flask easily.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, not. You still have to start celery separately. :s My bad.

Comment: I have a similar need to create n*(unique-queue single-process) celery workers depending on flask configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how do I run two apps and see STDOUT from both on the same terminal view?

Try starting celery in the background and flask in the foreground:

```
celery & ; flaskapp.py;
```

then `ctrl-c` will kill flaskapp.py and `kill %1` will kill celery.

Comment: Thanks, but this is basically identical to manually running. Flask+Celery often needs even more than two processes (for example, my setup currently uses 5), so I'm looking for a fully automated solution.